# Remote machine running XP won't shutdown, which processes should I kill and in what order?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, shutdown, remote-access

Unable to restart or shutdown remote Windows XP using psshutdown or psexec/shutdown. I tried `shutdown -s -t 0`, but this failed. Pulling the power isn't an option as no one at machine to do this.

I'm still able to run tasklist and taskkill on the remote machine.

Is it possible to trigger a fairly safe shutdown by killing processes?

- If so, which ones and in what order?
- If not, is there another way of performing a shutdown?

Comment: If there is no one to pull the plug, who's going to turn it back on?

Comment: have you tried shutdown /i ?

Comment: @DarthAndroid have you ever heard of Wake-on-Lan?

Comment: @kinokijuf ... My bad. I've heard plenty about it, but it just didn't cross my mind for some reason.

Comment: What happens when you run psshutdown? If the machine is still running you could start the Task Manager and see what process(es) are still alive.

Comment: @DartAndroid: WakeOnLAN!

Answer (score 5):

If you kill `lsass.exe` the machine will reboot, shutting down you have to execute a `shutdown` command.  `shutdown -s -f -t 05`    that will force a shutdown with a 5 second timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open taskmanager and choose "shutdown" from the menu, worked for me